# MySQL Query for 4 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I apologise in advance if this might seem simple as my assignment needs to be passed in 2 hours time and I don't have enough time to do some further research as I have another pending assignment to be submitted tonight. I only know the basic MYSQL commands and not these types. And this is one of the final questions left unanswered and is making me go nuts even if i have already read the JOIN documentation . Please help.

Say I have 4 tables

```
 _______________     _______________      _______________    _______________
|   customers   |   |     orders    |    | ordered_items |  |   products    |
|_______________|   |_______________|    |_______________|  |_______________|
|(pk)customer_id|   | (pk)order_id  |    |   (pk)id      |  |(pk)product_id |
|  first_name   |   |(fk)customer_id|    | (fk)order_id  |  |     name      |
|  last_name    |   |     date      |    |(fk)product_id |  |  description  |
|   contact_no  |   |               |    |    quantity   |  |     price     |
|_______________|   |_______________|    |_______________|  |_______________|
```

How would i be able to query all the products ordered by (eg: customer_id = '5')

I only know basic SQL like straight forward queries on 1 table and joins from 2 different, but since its 4 different tables having different relations to one another, how would i be able to get all the products ordered by a particular customer id?

Because its like get all the products from ordered products where order_id = (* orders by customer_id = 5).

But what can be an optimised and best practice way in doing this type of query

Comment: Have you looked into `JOIN`s?

Comment: @DaneHillard .. Yes I have but at the moment, i can only clearly understand and create queries ranging from 2-3 different tables, but I am yet to learn this type of scenario. Im no expert and still studying   from college. - also, its hard to have downvotes on someone asking a genuine question in a student perspective.. I cant figure this out in just a day, im just new at this.

Comment: @GitKidd: This forum is to help those that have done their due diligence before bringing questions forward.  This question is fairly basic, and it's difficult to assume that you have in fact tried something unless you actually present some reasonable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to join 3 tables - `orders`, `order_items`, and `products`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.*
FROM products
JOIN order_items USING (product_id)
JOIN orders USING (order_id)
WHERE orders.customer_id = 35
```

As many have mentioned, you would do yourself a big favor by learning about table [JOINS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).  There isn't much difference in the syntax between joining 2 tables to joining 4 or more.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) is a highly recommended resource for practicing and sharing your queries.

Comment: @MarkBannister .. yup, that's what i was trying to think as well :)

Comment: thank you very much. I may not be familiar with the DISTINCT and USING syntax yet as I havent used them before in a query with JOINS and other syntax that are included in the query but now that theres an example code, I've gained more understand into how to achieve the results that I wanted.. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GitKidd: `USING` is for natural joins, where the corresponding columns in the associated tables have the same name.  A more conventional approach is to use `ON table1.some_column = table2.other_column`, which works even where the column names are not identical.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment because you appear to be new to SQL.  You need to learn basic syntax for queries (which is why you are getting downvoted).

But you also ask about form.  The data structure is actually pretty well laid out.  I do have two comments.  First, you should be consistent about how you name the id columns.  For `Ordered_Items`, the id should be `ordered_item_id`.

Second, you should avoid using SQL special words for columns names and table names.  Instead of `date`, use `OrderDate`.

Comment: thank you sir.  I appreciate your advice and would like to thank you for your comment. - i just put (date) and (id) because I am really running out of time to specify the whole attributes of the table. would like to apologize for not using best practice. :)